# How to set body for file upload from javascript to Zoho Creator

Tags: javascript, post, file-upload

I need to upload an image file from javascript to zoho creator using rest api of zoho creator which is given here (https://www.zoho.com/creator/help/api/rest-api/rest-api-upload-file.html). But in this no parameter is available for attaching the file. from my survey regarding this, it requires a body formation to upload a file. So I need to know how to set the body and how to upload into zoho creator. Please help me!! I am using following line to capture image. and it is downloading to my local disk clearly. But now I need to upload that into zoho creator

```
var strmime="image/jpeg";
renderer.domElement.toDataURL(strmime,0.75);
```

Comment: Do you use JQuery or something similar on your site?

Comment: @AndréReichelt .  I am new to javascript. I can use JQuery if you say the exact method.

Comment: Use the `$.post` method. Your first parameter is the target URL and the second parameter is the data you would like to send. https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: But I already tried that @AndréReichelt. It shows the error as    "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://creator.zoho.com/api/jayakannan/json/test/form/test/record/add' from origin 'http://awesomesimple.96.lt' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

Comment: This means, that the operator of the API (likely zoho.com) doesn't allow you to use their API from your domain. The only possible way to sort this out is, to contact the site administrator and ask him or her, to add your domain to the CORS policy, or to grant general access.

Comment: Maybe this post will help you. Otherwise I would contact their support team. https://help.zoho.com/portal/community/topic/cross-domain-ajax-to-enter-table-rows

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply @AndréReichelt. I will check and let you know the  further update

Comment: Do you know that, how to upload the file from javascript through php. Because php may support it. So can you help me?

Comment: Well, you could create some kind of a proxy, where you basically recreate their API functions on your server. From there, you access their API through php. Then you push back the answer to your client. But that's kinda hacky, if you ask me.

Comment: The Record Creating API is working nicely. The file upload only not working. I think I need to add header and some other things with it to form a body before sending that. Do you know anything related to that? @AndréReichelt

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know their API well enough. But reading this forum post, that I've linked above, it seems like they're having some serious issues with their API.

Comment: But I know there api. Now I need to know that, how to set the body by adding header,encoder etc ..for data to upload to zoho creator. @AndréReichelt do you know that . If you know. Please help!!!

Comment: Please look into the JQuery documentation for the `$.post` method, or the documentation of your respective XHR library. There you should find the information needed on how to add the required headers. If you want to solve it with a PHP proxy, I can't help you, because I'm not a PHP dev.

But as I already said: It is technically absolutely impossible to get rid of the CORS error from your code. This is a security feature implemented into all browsers. ZOHO must gain your domain awesomesimple.96.lt CORS access to their API, otherwise it will not work.

Comment: Thanks for your kind information @AndréReichelt.

Comment: I hope, that it'll help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please look into the JQuery documentation for the `$.post` method, or the documentation of your respective XHR library. There you should find the information needed on how to add the required headers for this API.

It would also be possible to tunnel the request through your own PHP server as a proxy as described in the comments above. That way, you might me able to work around the problem by using a php implementation that does ignore the CORS header.

But as I already said: It is technically absolutely impossible to get rid of the CORS error from your Javascript code. This is a security feature implemented into all relevant browsers. The developer of the API, ZOHO, must gain your domain awesomesimple.96.lt CORS access to their API, otherwise it will not work from the browser directly. Please contact their technical support in case.